# filled text input while dropdown click php pdo

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

i used to filled the text input while dropdown clicked. but after i choose from dropdown, the text input still empty. i have echo $jsArray and it shows the data. text input should  have get the data while i choose from dropdown. here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo $jsArray; ?>
function changeValue(id){
document.getElementById('harga_satuan').value = hargaSatuan[id].satu;
};

</script>

<form action='create_detail.php' method='post'>

    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>No. Detail PO </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='detail_id' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $number; ?>' required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <div id="angka">
            <div id="input">
            <td>Quantity Yang Dipesan</td>
            <td><input type='text' class='qty_order' id='qty_order' name='qty_order' class='form-control'  onkeyup="hitung()"></td>
            </div>
            </div>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <div id="angka">
            <div id="input">
            <td>Harga Per Unit(Rp)</td>
            <td><input type='text' class='harga_satuan' id='harga_satuan' name='harga_satuan' class='form-control' onkeyup="hitung()"></td>
            </div>
            </div>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>ID Barang</td>
            <td>
            <?php
            // read from the database
            include_once 'objects/barang.php';

            $barang = new Barang($db);
            $stmt = $barang->read();

            // put them in a select drop-down
            echo "<select class='form-control' id='id_barang' name='id_barang' onchange='changeValue(this.value)'>";
                echo "<option>Select ..</option>";

                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $id_barang = $row['id_barang'];
                    $nama_barang = $row['nama_barang'];
                    $harga_satuan = $row['harga_satuan'];
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id_barang'] . "'>" . $row['id_barang'] . "</option>";
                    $jsArray .= 'hargaSatuan["' . $row['id_barang'] . '"] = {satu:"' . addslashes($row['harga_satuan']) . '"};\n';
                }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

but on the text input the data doesnt show. could you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function changeValue(){
  var sbox = document.getElementById("id_barang");
  document.getElementById('harga_satuan').value = sbox.options[sbox.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

and call function like this

```
echo "<select class='form-control' id='id_barang' name='id_barang' onchange='changeValue()'>";
```

Comment: it works but text input suppose to show the price called harga_satuan instead of id_barang. The result was show the id_barang, not harga_satuan. how?